# maple: plotting result of a numerical dsolve

Tags: plot, procedure, maple

I have to solve a differential equation numerically; so to say:

```
diff(y(x), x)+x^2-15*x = 5
```

with the initial conditions:

```
inc := y(0) = 0
```

the solution is of course:

```
sol := dsolve({f, inc}, numeric);
```

which results in:

> proc(x_rkf45)  ...  end

Now I want to plot `y(x)` for `x=0..2` for instance.
What shoudl I do?
the code:

```
plot(sol(x), x = 0 .. 2);
```

does not work!

> Warning, unable to evaluate the function to numeric values in the
>   region; see the plotting command's help page to ensure the calling
>   sequence is correct

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different ways to do that.

The first is to use the `DEtools[DEplot]` command, which both solves and plots. It's input is the differential equation(s) and one or more sets of intitial conditions (as opposed to something that `dsolve(...,numeric)` returns).

The `DEplot` command has lots of options. You can turn off inclusion of the field plot, for example.

```
restart:

deq := diff(y(x), x)+x^2-15*x = 5:

ic := y(0) = 0:

DEtools[DEplot](deq, y(x), x=0..2, [ic]);
```

[image]

The next way is to call `dsolve(...,numeric)` as you did, and to pass what it returns to the `plots:-odeplot` command.

```
sol := dsolve({deq, ic}, numeric):

plots:-odeplot(sol, x=0..2);
```

[image]

Yet another way is to pass `dsolve` the additional `output=listprocedure` option so that it returns a list of procedures. Any of those can then be extracted and used to compute at a point or used by passing to the usual `plot` command.

```
sollist := dsolve({deq, ic}, numeric, output=listprocedure):

Y := eval(y(x),sollist):

Y(1.0);
                          12.1666666666667

plot( Y, 0..2 );
```

[image]

See the help pages for [`DEtools[DEplot]`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DEtools%2FDEplot), [`plots:-odeplot`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeplot) or [plot,options](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot,options) for more details on customizing the resulting plots.

If you choose to go the `odeplot` way and also wish to include the field plot then you can augment the plot using [`plots:-display`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots,display) and [`plots:-fieldplot`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots,fieldplot).

Comment: If the answer meets all your needs then you can toggle it as being the accepted answer.